# Filter on window function according to hour

Tags: sql, postgresql, greenplum

I want to use two different (yet similar) window functions to calculate two values
`SUM` and `COUNT` on `is_active over user_id+item`, only up to the time of the row - minus 1 hour.
My intuition was use ROWS `UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` but that way I can't filter over the time

```
COUNT(1) OVER(PARTITION BY user_id, item ORDER BY req_time ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) 
SUM(is_active) OVER(PARTITION BY user-id, item ORDER BY req_time ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
```

However, that doesn't take under consideration the '1 hour ago' interval factor

Consider the following data:

```
user_id |     req_time       | item  | is_active |  
--------+--------------------+-------------------+---
1   | 2011-01-01 12:00:00|   1   |     0     |
1   | 2011-01-01 12:30:00|   1   |     1     |
1   | 2011-01-01 15:00:00|   1   |     1     |
1   | 2011-01-01 16:00:00|   1   |     0     |
1   | 2011-01-01 16:00:00|   2   |     0     |
1   | 2011-01-01 16:20:00|   2   |     1     |
2   | 2011-02-02 11:00:00|   1   |     1     |
2   | 2011-02-02 13:00:00|   1   |     0     |
1   | 2011-02-02 16:20:00|   1   |     0     |
1   | 2011-02-02 16:30:00|   2   |     0     |
```

I expect the following results: "value 1" is SUM(is_active) and "value 2" is COUNT(1):

```
user_id |     req_time       | item  | value 1 | value 2 |  
--------+--------------------+-----------------+---------+
1   | 2011-01-01 12:00:00|   1   |    0    |    0    |
1   | 2011-01-01 12:30:00|   1   |    0    |    0    |
1   | 2011-01-01 15:00:00|   1   |    1    |    2    |
1   | 2011-01-01 16:00:00|   1   |    2    |    3    |
1   | 2011-01-01 16:00:00|   2   |    0    |    0    |
1   | 2011-01-01 16:20:00|   2   |    0    |    0    |
2   | 2011-02-02 11:00:00|   1   |    0    |    0    |
2   | 2011-02-02 13:00:00|   1   |    1    |    1    |
1   | 2011-02-02 16:20:00|   1   |    2    |    4    |
1   | 2011-02-02 16:30:00|   2   |    1    |    2    |
```

I'm using Greenplum 4.21 which is based on Postgresql 8.2.15

Thanks in advance!
gilibi

Comment: Postgresql 8.2 does not have window functions. Did you try your query?

Comment: Postgresql 8.2 doesn't have window function but Greenplum 4.2 does have them. The query that I added in the question runs perfectly, except for the '1 hour ago' condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[8.3 at SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!10/a7ea5/8). Only one subselect.

```
select user_id, req_time, item, v[1] as value1, v[2] as value2
from (
    select t.*,
        (
            select array[
                coalesce(sum(is_active::integer), 0),
                count(*)
                ] as v
            from t s
            where
                user_id = t.user_id
                and item = t.item
                and req_time <= t.req_time - interval '1 hour'
        ) as v
    from t
) s
order by req_time, user_id, item
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how to do this with window functions, as least easily.

The easiest way I know is with correlated subqueries in the `select` clause:

```
select t.*,
       (select count(*) from t t2
        where t2.user_id = t.user_id and t2.item = t.item and
              t2.req_time < t.req_time - interval '1 hour'
       ) as value1,
       (select SUM(is_active) from t t2
        where t2.user_id = t.user_id and t2.item = t.item and
              t2.req_time < t.req_time - interval '1 hour'
       ) as value2
from t
```

You can do this *without* the correlated subquery.  It is just a bit more cumbersom . . .

```
select t.user_id, t.req_time, t.item,
       count(*) as value1,
       sum(t2.isactive) as value2
from t left outer join
     t t2
     on t.user_id = t2.user_id and
        t.item = t2.item and
        t2.req_time < t.req_time - interval '1 hour'
group by t.user_id, t.req_time, t.item
```

This may be even more efficient than the correlated subquery version (because there are two correlations).  And, it should work in GreenPlum.  I didn't realize that it lacks support for correlated subqueries.  That is quite a significant break from ANSI.

Comment: This is where CROSS APPLY would have shined, had PostgreSQL had it. I mean, you could then have performed one subselect instead of two.

Comment: I'm affraid that Greenplum (and I believe that most of Posgresql if not all) doesn't have correlated subqueries

Comment: @gilibi PostgreSQL does have correlated subqueries.